# a web component (using lit-element) for rating stars

Tags: web-component, lit-element

It can be used to rate something.
The rating is already available (e.g. average of ratings provided by large number of users), we just need to depict the current rating by using stars (consider value up to 1 decimal point in case of rating in decimals)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla Web Component version [from my DEV.to post](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/twinkle-twinkle-web-component-star-23d7)

For a Lit version, you only have to *add* some extra lines of code...

```js
  customElements.define("star-rating", class extends HTMLElement {
    set rating(rate) {
      if (!String(rate).includes("%")) rate = Number(rate) / this.stars * 100 + "%";
      this.querySelector(":nth-child(2)").setAttribute("width", rate); //2nd rect
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let {bgcolor,stars,nocolor,color,rating} = this.attributes;
      let repeat = (count, func) => Array(count).fill().map(func);
      this.stars = ~~stars.value || 5;
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${this.stars*100} 100" style=cursor:pointer>` +
        `<rect height=100 fill=${nocolor.value} width=100% />` +
        `<rect height=100 fill=${color.value} />` +
        repeat(this.stars    , (i, n) => `<path fill=${bgcolor.value} d="m${ n*100 } 0h102v100h-102v-100m91 42a6 6 90 00-4-10l-22-1a1 1 90 01-1 0l-8-21a6 6 90 00-11 0l-8 21a1 1 90 01-1 1l-22 1a6 6 90 00-4 10l18 14a1 1 90 010 1l-6 22a6 6 90 008 6l19-13a1 1 90 011 0l19 13a6 6 90 006 0a6 6 90 002-6l-6-22a1 1 90 010-1z"/>`) +
        repeat(this.stars * 2, (i, n) => `<rect x=${ n*50 } n=${n} opacity=0 width=50 height=100 ` +
          ` onclick="this.closest('star-rating').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))" ` +
          ` onmouseover="this.closest('star-rating').rating=${(n+1)/2}"/>`) +
        "</svg>";
      this.rating = rating.value;
    }
  });
```

```html
<star-rating stars=5 rating="3.2"
             bgcolor="green" nocolor="grey" color="gold"></star-rating>
             
<br>

<star-rating stars=7 rating="50%"
             bgcolor="rebeccapurple" nocolor="beige" color="goldenrod"></star-rating>
```